# How can I pass the type for the List I want return?

Tags: java, list, gson

My scenario:

I get a jsonArray, I want to convert this jsonArray to a List of desired type; ie `List<Integer>`, `List<String>` etc.

Suppose I have the following method:

```
public static List jsonArrayToJavaList(JsonArray jsonArray, TYPE TYPE) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, new TypeToken<List<TYPE>>() {}.getType());
}
```

How do I pass in the `TYPE`?

I want to do this because this method could be used by other people and I don't want to duplicate this code for each type of list I want...

I also tried:

```
public static List jsonArrayToJavaList(JsonArray jsonArray, final Class c) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, new TypeToken<List<c>>() {}.getType());
}
```

I see the error saying unknown class c.

Comment: My guess is that you can leverage `Class<T>` somehow.

Comment: @DennisMeng could you provide a snippet? I think I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: I don't have anything concrete yet (hence why it's still just a guess). If I get something concrete before anyone else posts, I'll post an answer. That being said, you could update the question with what you did and why it didn't work. Who knows? It could have been something minor.

Comment: @DennisMeng i added my code with the Class<T>

Comment: Ah. Well, in your code snippet, you're using the raw type, and even if you weren't, remember that `List<Class<T>>` isn't the same thing as a `List<T>`.

Comment: i updated to return List<Class>, it still complains about c been unknown.

Comment: I believe you would need to declare your method as: public static <T> List jsonArrayToJavaList(JsonArray jsonArray, T type) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, new TypeToken<List<type>>() {}.getType());
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating lists of dynamic types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894860/creating-lists-of-dynamic-types) - the answer is: you can't due to type erasure.

Comment: @BrianRoach that looks to be the case, kinda sucks that i would need to duplicate jsonArrayToJava{type}List

Answer (score 0):

*Java doesn't yet provide an official way to represent generic types*. As stated in the [javadoc](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html), the TypeToken has been provided in order to give the possibility to represent these types. So, the simple solution would be to use it as a parameter to the jsonArrayToJavaList method. However it will be just an indirection to the call of fromJson.