# Creating lists of dynamic types

Tags: java, android, json, list, gson

So, I'm working right now on trying to figure out how to parse a large number of different JSON objects without having to hard-code functions to serialize and deserialize each of the objects. I started using Gson, and that has been working pretty well. A problem begins to appear though when I am trying to use a list of objects.

I would like to create a function that will work with any of my data model objects that I can pass a JSONArray and the class type that the JSON contains, so that I would have a call that looks something like this -

```
response = JSONHelper.createObjectList(jsonArray, DataObject.class);
```

*Btw, I'm not posting from my dev machine, so forgive me if there are a few typos in my code.*

I tried to create that effect by writing something like this (inside my JSONHelper class) -

```
public List createObjectList(JSONArray jsonArray, Class type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<type>>() {}.getType();

    List<type> data = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, listType);

    return data;
}
```

Okay, so obviously that isn't working code, but that is kinda how I wanted to be able to get this to work. I tried several different ways and variations, but I haven't been able to figure out anything that works really nicely.

I am new to the Android/Java world, so i'm still learning the in's and out's of the language. If someone could give me some tips on how I could achieve what I am looking for, it would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: You can't do what you're trying to do in Java because of type erasure.

That's the *reason* you have to use `TypeToken` and pass a `Type` to Gson's `fromJson()` method; the type information for `T` isn't available at runtime. Generics in Java are for the most part just compile time type checking.

Ideally you'd like to be able to do this:

```
public <T> List<T> createList(JsonArray a, Class<T> clazz)
{
    Type t = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(a, t);
}
```

But you can't, because T gets erased.  If you try this you'll find the result completely confusing; you get a `List` back, but it won't *actually* contain your class and throw a cast exception.

Effectively, your method would have to look like this:

```
public <T> List<T> createList(JsonArray a, Type t)
{
    List<T> list = new Gson().fromJson(a, t);
    return list;
}
```

Which of course would be silly since you're now calling a method you wrote instead of just calling the method in Gson.

**Edit to add:**

Thinking about it, there's way around this for `List` types. You can use arrays:

```
public <T> List<T> createList(JsonArray a, Class<T[]> c)
{
    T[] array = new Gson().fromJson(a, c);
    return Arrays.asList(array);
}
```

Because you're not trying to rely on the generic type from *inside* a `List` and instead are passing an array type for the class... it works. A bit messy, but it works:

```
List<MyPojo> list = createList(a, MyPojo[].class);
```